# Аудио с сайта, Java

Tags: java

- Как сделать в Java приложении возможным добавление музыки прямо из сети?
- Как мне подгрузить звук в моё приложение, который воспроизводится на html странице? Я не хочу загружать сам звуковой файл, я просто хочу чтобы звук передавался в моё приложения, так, как будто я открываю страницу в браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не так давно видел интересную библиотеку `http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html`. А вот пример кода:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, JavaLayerException {
        String url = "https://psv4.userapi.com/c813137/u1444216/audios/1a174239ef2d.mp3";
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
        Player player = new Player(is);
        player.play();
    }
}
```

Надеюсь решение подойдет.

Если используете maven, то вот как подключить dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Кроме того есть базовый java plugin, который называется JMF - [качать и настраивать здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) (но насколько я знаю он не так активно поддерживается)

Comment: всё было бы ок, возможно, но тут исключение Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:... Я попробовал через URLConnection сделать параметры соединения такими url.openConnection().setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); Это помогло, но при получение InputStream у объекта URLConnection программа просто завершалась с кодом завершение 0, но никакой музыки я не слышал

Comment: @ProstoCoder это при запуске моего кода? Или Вы свой какой-то URL вставляете?

Comment: Это мой URL, а ваш URL вообще не существует 404 Not Found

Comment: @ProstoCoder странно - проверил во всех браузерах анонимно и с полной очисткой кэша - должен был работать. Но это второстепенно - а Ваш URL доступен через интернет -я его проверить могу? Похоже, что дело не в коде, а в том, что Вы пытаетесь открыть URL который требует дополнительных credentials. Короче говоря если Вы дадите URL и тестовые креды, то можно было бы подправить ответ. А так выглядит как Ваше частное поведение, не вызванное самим кодом.

Comment: вот мой URL http://best-muzon.cc/online/listen90013.html

Comment: @ProstoCoder Вы указываете ссылку на странице, а не на stream. Вот ссылка на первый трек с Вашей страницы: [Twenty One Pilots  -  Heathens](http://dnl1.best-muzon.cc/dl/online/A5BY4g5p2TTZpJ7X1LD3aQ/1505687555/songs12/2016/09/twenty-one-pilots-heathens-(best-muzon.cc).mp3). Я смотрю прямую ссылку через Chrom (1. Нажимаете Ctrl + Shift + I; 2. Переключаетесь на "Network"; 3. Перезагружаете страницу и фильтруете таблицу по типу "media" - там будет прямая ссылка на mp3 файл).

Comment: ага, теперь понятно, спасибо большое!

Comment: я возможно уже вас замучал, но у меня появился ещё один вопрос. В JavaFX есть WebView, я могу как-то с WebView получать все Media ссылки, которые на нём проскакивают?

Comment: @ProstoCoder классный вопрос, но я бы задал его в отдельном вопросе... что-то типа "Как спарсить mp3 файлы с web страницы, используя java". Насколько я помню это можно сделать с использованием jsoup, но нужно поискать\освежить знания.

Comment: не совсем все, только те, которые подгрузятся. Т.е. я нажимаю на кнопку и проскакивает Media ссылка, от который идёт музыка. Мне нужны только вот эти ссылки, это возможно вообще ? :D

Comment: @ProstoCoder понятно. Но похоже, что WebView не позволяет грузить media контент - поэтому я сомневаюсь. Но я бы отдельный вопрос задал все же - наверняка найдется тот, кто похожей проблемой занимался.

Comment: уже задал, если интересно вот ссылка на его https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719505/Как-парсить-media-ссылки-которые-проскакивают-при-нажатии-на-кнопки